# adding unsigned int to unsigned int*

Tags: c++, c, pointer-arithmetic, unsigned-integer

My development environment consists of the g++ cross compiler for ARM OMAP Sitata. I discovered an unusual nuance of simple pointer arithmetic, when adding an unsigned int to an unsigned int*, as follows:

```
unsigned int* dst_base_addr;
unsigned int* dst_addr; 
unsigned int dst_offset;
```

Simply attempting to add an (unsigned int) to an (unsigned int*)

```
dst_addr = dst_base_addr + dst_offset;
```

The above is not interpreted as one might naively think but actually produces the following equivalent result

```
dst_addr = (unsigned int*)((unsigned int)dst_base_addr + (dst_offset << 2));
```

The remedy is of course to do proper type conversion as follows

```
dst_addr = (unsigned int*)((unsigned int)dst_base_addr + dst_offset);
```

Question: Why is proper type conversion even necessary in this situation?

Comment: To avoid mistakes.

Comment: `dst_addr = dst_base_addr + dst_offset;` without allocating memory for dst_addr is not good.

Comment: `dst_addr = (unsigned int*)((unsigned int)dst_base_addr + dst_offset);` but this is wrong, pointer arithmetic doesn't work like that

Comment: This is not even close to being "an unusual nuance", it's 100% bog standard and very well-defined in how C's pointer arithmetic works. Remember that `*(p+i) = p[i]`, and perhaps it becomes a bit clearer/easier to remember.

Comment: The remedy ("of course") is to do *correct* type conversion; converting a pointer to `unsigned int` is *not* correct, since there is no guarantee that an `unsigned int` is big enough to hold a pointer; on many architectures, the result will drop the high-order bits of the pointer and therefore be meaningless. Use `dst_addr = (unsigned int*)((char*)dst_base_addr + dst_offset);` (Or you could use `uintptr_t` if it exists on your implementation.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The above is not interpreted as one might naively think but actually produces the following equivalent result

Pointer arithmetic in C (and presumably C++) is done in units the size of the thing pointed to. If you add n to an `int*` the code generated will add as many bytes as it takes to represent n `int`s i.e. probably 4 * n if `int` is 32 bits (4 bytes on most sane architectures).

This is standard C behaviour.